# Airflow: Best way to pass BigQuery result as XCom

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm using `Cloud Composer (Airflow)` to export data from `MySQL` into `BigQuery` daily.
The MySQL table has an incremental id as `PRIMARY KEY`. 
To append only the new rows every day I need to:

1. Query the BQ table to find the `max(id) AS bq_max_id`
2. Export the MySQL new data `WHERE id > bq_max_id` to GCS
3. Load the GCS data to BQ

To do the first step I need to use 2 operators

```
  select_max_id = bigquery_operator.BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='select_max_id',
        bql="""
            SELECT max(id) AS max_id
            FROM some_schema.some_table
        """,
        use_legacy_sql=False,
        destination_dataset_table='some_schema.xcom_value_table')

  pull_xcom_value = bigquery_get_data.BigQueryGetDataOperator(
        task_id='pull_xcom_value',
        dataset_id='some_schema',
        table_id='xcom_value_table')
```

And then I use a `BashOperator`to delete the xcom_value_table.

Is there a better way of passing a BQ query result as an XCom than creating a table and using 3 operators?

Comment: I do not understand the code since only a part of it is being posted. This seems like a interesting way of xcom usage.

Comment: @andscoop and Iñigo - Thanks. That solved my problem, guess I missed it since was tagged as Postgre